# What is wrong about the following phrases about the number of women in state legislatures?

Tags: tense, idioms

> According to a recent study by Rutgers University, […] in every election since 1968.
>
> [A] the number of women in state legislatures has grown
>   [B] the number of women who are in state legislatures have grown
>   [C] there has been growth in the number of women in state legislatures
>   [D] a growing number of women have been in state legislatures
>   [E] women have been growing in number in state legislatures

What is the problem with options C and E?

Comment: If you have a link to an online copy, please add it.  Perhaps some assumptions apply which you haven't shown.

Comment: If I were to judge from what you have written, option B would be wrong because the subject is singular ("number") and the verb is plural ("have grown").

Comment: What does "english SC question" mean? Apart from the laughable **B**, the merits/demerits of all the alternatives are incredible subtle (I've got no clear ideas on any of them, despite having a degree in English). I don't see how you can be expected to answer questions like this if you're still not even able to capitalise the **English** language reliably.

Answer (score 2):

I assume OP is aware that **B** is completely invalid (*have* should be *has*, since *the number* is singular). All the next three are all "grammatical", but flawed from my point of view...

**C** is somewhat "clumsy" phrasing in any context. But looking at instances of [been growth in the number](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22growth%20in%20the%20number%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22been%20growth%20in%20the%20number%22&oq=%22been%20growth%20in%20the%20number%22&gs_l=serp.3...16190.17261.0.17578.5.5.0.0.0.0.140.511.3j2.5.0...0.0...1c.1.17.psy-ab.XPSMxKtOjhw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47810305,d.d2k&fp=d7cc20034826e2ed&biw=1296&bih=930) in Google Books (despite the optimistic "guestimate", there are actually only 40) you'll see most of them are in relatively complex contexts comparing/contrasting *growth* in one area with growth/decrease in another. In OP's standalone construction, it just doesn't work very well (we'd probably say ***an*** increase, but not *growth*, and certainly not ***a*** growth).

**D** is also pretty awful, but even harder to explain. I think the problem is that *a growing number of women* is simply the ***subject*** of the statement. We expect the sentence to then say something meaningful *about* those women, but it turns out they just "are" [somewhere]. In fact, the whole point of the statement is to tell us that *the number of women **has grown***, but that's just buried in the phrasing of the subject.

**E** is the least flawed of these three, but I still don't like it. I think here the problem is that *X's have been growing in number* is a format that would normally be used where *X* is an identifiable "defining category" (i.e. - each *X* is the same as every other *X*; all that matters is how many/how much *X* we have in total). That doesn't really sit well with me in the context of "women in state legislatures", since we're talking about numerous different individuals who *just happen* to be women. They're not part of some organised collection of "all women" outside the legislature, gradually increasing their presence *inside* it.

Answer (score 0):

E implies that the women themselves have grown which isn't the point.  It is the number that are women which is a subtle difference.

C uses prepositional phrases to state key points of the answer, that the growth is in the number of women holding positions here.

Comment: E says “growing in number” which certainly doesn't imply the women themselves have grown.  Regarding C, are you saying no more than that it's periphrastic?  Yes, but so are some of the others.  In the question as edited (with “[…]” to be replaced by one of A...E) C appears to be the only semantically sound answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the question from 1000 SC (Sentence Correction). The official answer is **A**.

Here is the reasoning I've read over the web.

- **A** is correct
- **B** breaks subject-verb agreement: "the number" is singular
- **C** is mostly just a matter of idiom. If something (X) has grown, then "X has grown" is idiomatic; "there has been growth in X" is not idiomatic. If you're going to write this with a preposition, the thing that's actually growing takes *of*, not *in*: *growth of the population in Arizona*. [This is the reasoning given by MGMAT Instructor, Ron Purewal.]
- As mentioned by [@FumbleFingers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/126/fumblefingers), **D** tells about the growing number of women.
- **E** is not correct because women are growing, not the number.

I'm not an English Expert but above reasoning is captured from all over the web. Also as it is SC question we are asked to choose the best of given option.